# Angular : avoid showing 'No results found' first if result is true

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement, angular-ng-if

I have search input where user will enter value and matched records will be shown. I am calling `getSearchResults` in `ngOnit`.

I need to show result when found else if api status is false then need to show 'No results found.'

But when I get api response true then it first shows 'No results found' and then data found.

How can I avoid showing 'No results found' first if api status is true?

I have tried different `*ngIf` conditions but nothing working as expected.

**Ts**

```
  searchResults:any;
  searchResultsFlag:boolean = false;
  horseResults:any;
  userResults:any;

  getSearchResults(){
    this.SpinnerService.show();  
    this.horseService.SearchProfile(this.searchValue).subscribe((results) => {
    
      if (results['status'] === false) {
        this.SpinnerService.hide();  
        this.searchResultsFlag = false;
      } else {
        this.SpinnerService.hide();  
        this.searchResultsFlag = true;
        this.searchResults = results['data'];
        this.horseResults = this.searchResults.horses;
        this.userResults =this.searchResults.users;

      }

    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="horse_slider_wrap search_result_card" *ngIf="searchResultsFlag">
    <h5 class="mb-3" *ngIf="userResults && userResults.length>0">Matched User Results</h5>
    <div class="row">          
   
      <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let user of userResults">
        ....
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <h5 class="mb-3" *ngIf="horseResults && horseResults.length>0">Matched Horse Results</h5>
    <div class="row">   
      
      <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let horse of horseResults">
      ....
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
  <p *ngIf="!searchResultsFlag">No results found.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because while the http request to the API occurs, your searchResultsFlag os setted as false.

To fix it, you should create a loading flag:

```
searchResults:any;
  searchResultsFlag:boolean = false;
  loadingFlag = false;
  horseResults:any;
  userResults:any;

  getSearchResults(){
    this.SpinnerService.show();  
    this.loadingFlag = true;
    this.horseService.SearchProfile(this.searchValue).subscribe((results) => {
    
      if (results['status'] === false) {
        this.SpinnerService.hide();  
        this.searchResultsFlag = false;
      } else {
        this.SpinnerService.hide();  
        this.searchResultsFlag = true;
        this.searchResults = results['data'];
        this.horseResults = this.searchResults.horses;
        this.userResults =this.searchResults.users;

      }

      this.loadingFlag = false:

    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="horse_slider_wrap search_result_card" *ngIf="searchResultsFlag">
    <h5 class="mb-3" *ngIf="userResults && userResults.length>0">Matched User Results</h5>
    <div class="row">          
   
      <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let user of userResults">
        ....
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <h5 class="mb-3" *ngIf="horseResults && horseResults.length>0">Matched Horse Results</h5>
    <div class="row">   
      
      <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let horse of horseResults">
      ....
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
  <p *ngIf="!searchResultsFlag && !loadingFlag">No results found.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks . Its working. Just for curiosity I am asking, I had tried not to set `searchResultsFlag` to false at time of declaration. but that also not worked. Any idea why is that ? why we require new variable ? is it possible to manage this in one variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize loadingFlag=true, by default you are loading data, so you wont show text of No Result Data until you get response and modify loadingFlag=false